# Electric Flux in a Gaussian Surface

Tags: electrostatics, gauss-law

Why is electric flux of a charge everywhere inside a Gaussian Surface constant? I want explanation ( not from any equation ).

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, it's because we design the Gaussian surface that way.  Here's what I mean by that: Gauss's law works for any arbitrary closed surface, regardless of its shape.  The *total* flux through the surface must be proportional to the enclosed charge.  For most surfaces you could invent (and you really are free to invent them however you want as long as they're closed--that's the beauty of theoretical physics) the flux *wouldn't* be constant all around.  But if you actually want to calculate the charge distribution from the flux or vice versa, you'll run in to some impossibly ugly integrals.

But usually we can choose a Gaussian surface based on symmetry: if we have a point charge we use a sphere, if we have a line we use a cylinder, if we have a plane we use some sort of cube or box with edges perpendicular or parallel to the surface.  In those cases, symmetry dictates that the flux must be constant, which makes the integration simple.  All the examples you see are that way simply because those are the ones which can be solved.

Answer (score 0):

One way to think of it is to imagine a point source pushing out water. If you put some imaginary surface around the source, the total amount of water passing through that surface is the same as the amount of water being pushed out by the source. It doesn't matter what the shape of this surface is, the total amount of water passing through it will be the same (and equal to the amount of water from the source).